# How to obtain the wifi security type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to figure out of it is possible to obtain the security type of the network that the device is connected to (WEP/WPA). I know it is possible to get the SSID but I am having no luck getting the security type. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

For macOS you can use coreWLAN and then get the info you want from CWSecurity. But coreWLAN is not available for iOS and SystemConfiguration cannot give you that info.